# Using Predicate method - "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface"

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-stream, functional-interface

The third line will not compile, because `The target type of this expression must be a functional interface`:

```
Predicate<String> p = String::isBlank;
List.of("").stream().filter(p.negate());
List.of("").stream().filter((String::isBlank).negate()); // compile error
```

Why not? What's the difference between `String::isBlank` and `p`?

Comment: I get a different error when I try this with JDK 17: "method reference not expected here". Anyway, this probably happens because type inference is not smart enough to look through this expression; it doesn't make the connection that `filter` takes a `Predicate`, which means that `negate()` should return a `Predicate` and that therefore the target type of `String::isBlank` is a `Predicate`.

Comment: It works if you add a cast: `filter(((Predicate<String>) String::isBlank).negate());`

Comment: @Jesper Why would it even have to infer? Can `String::isBlank` be anything other than a `Predicate`?

Comment: Of course it can, the target type can be any interface that defines a method that takes a `String` and returns a `boolean`.

Comment: @Jesper Sounds like a predicate to me!

Comment: Yes, but what if I define my own `interface Example { boolean m(String s); }`? The method reference could just as well be an `Example` instead of a `Predicate`. Just from the method reference alone, the target type cannot be uniquely determined. Of course it matches `Predicate`, but it could also match any number of other functional interfaces.

Comment: basically you are expecting Java to go through all functional interfaces (standard and included libraries) to search one and the only one that has a `negate()` method returning a `Predicate`, and that *accepts*  a method which takes a `String` and returns `boolean`

Comment: Well there's still something fishy going on; `(String::isBlank).toString()` will not compile, whereas `p.toString()` will.

Comment: a method reference (`String::isBlank`) is not an instance neither class; it has no members (fields, methods, ... ) so we cannot invoke a method on it - `Predicate p` is a reference to an instance, as such it has members, including the ones inherited from `Object` (unless it is `null`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the difference between `String::isBlank` and `p`?

`p` has a type. `String::isBlank` does not.

From the Java Language Specification, [Type of a Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2),

> A method reference expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type `T` if `T` is a functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is congruent with the function type of the ground target type derived from `T`.

It then proceeds to define what "congruent" and "ground target type" means.  The relevant part to your question is, `String::isBlank` is not in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context, when you write it like this:

```
(String::isBlank).negate()
```

You might think this counts as an [invocation context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3), but invocation contexts are actually the arguments of method calls, like `someMethod(String::isBlank)`. As the spec says:

> Invocation contexts allow an argument value in a method or constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1, §15.9, §15.12) to be assigned to a corresponding formal parameter.

Anyway, *because* `String::isBlank` is not in any of those contexts, the spec doesn't say anything about its type. In fact, [just a bit up the page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2), it states,

> It is a compile-time error if a method reference expression occurs in a program in someplace other than an assignment context (§5.2), an invocation context (§5.3), or a casting context (§5.5).

So those contexts turn out to be the *only* contexts that method references can occur in!

I didn't design the Java Language, so I can't tell you how the designers thought when they designed this, but I know that this design is rather simple to implement, compared to, say, allowing method references *everywhere*, which would require considering a *lot* more edge cases, and how this would interact with other language features. If method references are just limited to these three contexts, there won't be as much edge cases to consider, and it's relatively easy to figure out what types they are, and if you want to use them in a random expression somewhere, this design also allows you to do that just by casting:

```
((Predicate<String>)String::isBlank).negate()
```

It's a fairly good compromise, in my opinion.

If you are still wondering "why didn't they implement it like ... instead?" I recommend checking out [Eric Lippert's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293815/is-it-subjective-to-ask-about-why-something-wasnt-implemented-in-the-language/293819#293819).

Answer (score 2):

*Lambda expressions* and *method references* have **no type** by itself. They are so-called *poly expressions*, it means the way they will be interpreted depends on the context in which they appear.

For instance, in the statement below, *method references* `String::isBlank` conforms to the `Consumer` interface. It will compile and execute successfully:

```
List.<String>of().forEach(String::isBlank);
```

And in the following statement, the type or reference `String::isBlank` would be inferred as a `Function<String>`:

```
Stream.<String>of().map(String::isBlank);
```

The compiler gets confused when you're trying to chain method on something that has no type by itself, it has no information to infer what to which functional interface `String::isBlank` could conform in `(String::isBlank).negate()` just from the fact that the overall expression expected to be a `Predicate`. If you were expecting that method `negate()` would give a clue to the compiler, then this assumption is wrong, it not the way how *method resolution* works in Java. Firstly, the compiler needs to know the type and only then it would be looking a potentially applicable method, among the methods that belong to this type, not the opposite.

You need to provide a *context* if you want to use it like that. I.e. *method references* should appear in either of these types of context: *assignment context, invocation context, casting context*.

Here is an example of how we can use *invocation context*, the following code compile:

```
List.of("").stream().filter(m(String::isBlank).negate());
```

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> m(Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return predicate;
}
```

In this is an example of *casting context* already posted in the comments by *@Jesper*:

```
filter(((Predicate<? super String>) (String::isBlank)).negate())
```

Comment: @Jesper Sure, I meant `Consumer`. Thanks, amended.